# Get all changed files for a given directory in a branch

Tags: logging, mercurial

Our project switched over from SVN to Mercurial recently.  In SVN, to version our css/js files we get the latest changed revision from the directory that they reside in and use it as a prefix for the packed filenames.

We want to use the same method in Mercurial.  Unfortunately, it seems easier said than done, although it may be caused by our branching method.

In a nutshell, we have a main branch (trunk).  Every couple of weeks we branch from trunk to create a production beta, which will eventually be merged into our live branch.

Now at the moment, we're essentially using

```
hg log -b live some_folder/js
hg log -b live some_folder/css
```

to get the changeset that most recently changed files in those directories.

The problem that we're running into is that our merge changesets aren't being detected using this method.  So if we merge in a changeset that modifies a file in some_folder/css, hg doesn't count it as having changed, since the file wasn't actually modified in the merge changeset, but in one of the changesets that is being merged.

We've also tried revsets to try to parse the logs, but it seems to have the same problem.  The only way to get hg log to list those files as changed seems to be to use the --stat option, but

```
hg log -b live --stat some_folder/css
```

doesn't show the changesets either.

I'm at the point where I'm considering just using

```
hg log -b live --stat
```

to get the log for the entire branch, then parsing it to find the changeset that most recently modified a file the directory, but I'd prefer not to since it seems like it'll get slower and slower as the branch gets bigger.

Any ideas on a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: But why is this a problem? If the file has changed, it will definitely show up in the log (of that file). And then the changeset number will be different from the previous release as well. So why does it matter which branch the change happened on?

Comment: We only want the version number changing if the file has been changed in our live branch.  Sometimes we push out hot fixes that don't modify the css/js at all, and we'd prefer that our users don't have to download the files again for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end there wasn't an easy way to do this, so I resorted to the following method:
Grab all logs for the branch in the last x days.  Iterate through all those logs using the stat command and stop on the first revision that affects the given branch.  If none in that date range affect the given path, grab the next x days worth of logs.  So:

```
hg log -b live -r "reverse(date('2011-05-12 to 2011-05-26'))" --template "{node} "
```

Then for each changeset

```
hg st --change <the_changeset> -I "some_folder/css"
```

When this returns any none empty value, I stop the loop and return the changeset id. Hopefully at some point revsets will support iterating through merged changes.

Answer (score 2):

I will caveat this answer by stating that I don't currently have Mercurial installed on this PC so can't verify the commands, but it may at least point you in a useful (?) direction.

You can use `hg status` specifying the `--rev` option to get the list of changes between two revisions, so using the revision notation, could you do the following:

```
hg status -b live --rev -2:-1 some_folder/css
```

In theory (here's where I get things very wrong :)), the options mean:

`--rev -2:-1` selects the parent of the working directory (I'm assuming you would still be there following the merge), and compares it to its own parent (`-2`). Specifying `-b live` would hopefully pick the parent in that branch, but as I've stated, I can't test this right now.